# How to differentiate between single and double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I added to my handler the function you shared, and it looks like this:

```
initMouseHandling:function(){
                    var dragged = null, 
                    _mouseP,
                    selected,
                    nearest = null,
                    show = true,
                    num_console = 0,
                    timeout,
                    clicks,
                    delay = 500;
                                        
                    
var handler =  {

 
   
single_double_click: function (element, clicked, double_click, timeout) {

$(element).observe('click', function (event) {
    ++clicks;
    if (clicks === 1) {
        var timeoutCallback = function (event) {
            if (clicks === 1) {
                clicked.call(this, event);
            } else {
                double_click.call(this, event);
            }
            clicks = 0;
        };
        timeoutCallback.bind(this, event).delay(timeout / 1000);
    }
}.bind(this));
return false;
},

clicked:function(e){
...
},
dragged:function(e){
...
},
dropped:function(e){
...
},
over_edge:function(e){
...
},
over_node:function(e){
...
},
double_click:function(e){
...
}}

canvas.mousemove(handler.over_node);
canvas.mousemove(handler.over_edge);
canvas.mousedown(handler.single_double_click);
//canvas.mousedown(handler.clicked);
//canvas.dblclick(handler.double_click);
}
```

It says:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'observe'"

Regardless of using `$(canvas)` or `$(window)` as I've seen in other places...

I don't know if I should introduce the handlers as parameters or not, why I cannot use "observe" and if for a case like mine I should call my handlers like that:

```
clicked.call(this, event);
double_click.call(this, event);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into jQuery's [dblclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no jquery function `observe` and the error tells you that.
To detect double clicks you start a timeout on the first click, 
cancel it if clicked in timeout duration (200ms) and trigger single click or trigger double click on next click:

```js
let timeout;
$("button").on("click", () => {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
    alert("double click")
    return;
  }

  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    alert("single click");
    timeout = null;
  }, 200); // 200ms, try other values for best ux
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```